# Is it beneficial to use DataAdapter.Update to update millions of records in a DataBaseTable?

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2012

I am supposed to update 2-3 fields in a DataBase Table having 10s of millions of records. I am doing the operation in a .Net application in batches of 100K(recursively) and updating the table by regular ADO.Net code and executing Stored Procs to update the table. This process is estimated to take 30 hours(probably because of IO and server roundtrips) like this and I have to do it in just 4.

Would DataAdapter.Update be any faster? Any suggestions on improving speed greatly appreciated.

Comment: follow this url it MAY be help to u ..https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330

Comment: I read this before. my prob is, the update I have to do is encryption by custom algo AES, thts a .Net library. I probably have to convert those encryption methods to SQLCLR functions and then run updates.. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Besides thats Oracle, it  is faster

Comment: You can use the SqlDataAdapter and specify the batch size that you are working with. Depending on the size of each record you could load it all into memory at once. You could look at the table size and based on that do a rough estimate of how much memory that would be. Otherwise you would have to load it and update it in chunks. The best way to give you an idea of if it will be fast enough is to test it, without that no one can say how long it will take because of variables like data size, whats being updated, index lookup in update command, network speed, cpu load, memory load etc. etc.

Comment: What about a stored proc accepting a table type variable with the next batch of encrypted values and save 99.99% of the roundtrips.

Comment: Will try if that doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

well i also have the same problem but we solve it my using the threading concept.
First make a list of dataset for 1000 or 10000 record in each
Than create a thread pool by calling
Task tsk = Task.factory.StartNew(()=>function_Name(list object));
Define the function_name and perform batch update using dataadapter
You will get huge difference ......

The pooled thread fired concurrently.